# How to configure simple rate limiting on Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have a simple Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul in front of my services. I would like to set **rate limiting** for all requests coming to this Zuul.

I have seen this post: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-zuul-rate-limit
However I have neither controllers in my Zuul or JPA repository. All routes Zuul receives from Eureka.

**Zuul**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class BlitzZuulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlitzZuulApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.properties**:

> spring.application.name=zuul
>   server.port = 7125
>   my.eureka.port=7126
>
> eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:${my.eureka.port}/eureka

**pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.marcosbarbero.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

How to configure Zuul for rate limiting and restrict the number of overall incoming requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following **application.yaml** file:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    my-service:
      path: /
  ratelimit:
    enabled: true
    repository: JPA
    policy-list:
      my-service:
        - limit: 2
          refresh-interval: 60
          type:
            - origin
  strip-prefix: true
```

At this point property *zuul.ratelimit.repository* should be not empty. There is some options listed if you miss it.

I start using JPA repository. For this *spring-boot-starter-data-jpa* dependency  should be added in a project and *datasource* should be configured as usual.

If you now start a project you will get this Exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'rate' doesn't
>   exist

In this source you can find *Rate.java* class in *config* folder with a structure:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=marcosbarbero/spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit/spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit-master/spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit-core/src/main/java/com/marcosbarbero/cloud/autoconfigure/zuul/ratelimit/RateLimitAutoConfiguration.java#

So **Rate** entity is:

```
@Entity
public class Rate {

    @Id
    private String key;
    private Long remaining;
    private Long remainingQuota;
    private Long reset;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date expiration;

    // constructor, getters and setters 
}
```

With this configuration and creating the table all works fine, Zuul saves information about request in the table. In my case 2 requests allowed in 60 seconds.

Comment: Is there any available information / benchmarks showing how this affects request throughput?